# Generate exponential distribution in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability, probability-density

I'm aware of the `random.expovariate` function but this is not what I need. 
I'd like to generate a stream of length `N` in which each element `i` between `1` and `M` is chosen with probability 1/(2^(i+1))
Thus,element `0` is chosen with probability 1/2, element `1` with probability 1/4, element 2 with probability  1/8,  etc.

Is there any simple way to do that in python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simple solution is to revert the function and predict the proba to find the number:

```
def generate():
    proba = random.random()
    max = 0
    for i in range(1,M+1):
         max += (1/2)**i
         if(proba<= max):
              return i-1
    return generate()
```

if M is small the distribution is not converging and thus not all [0,1] is reacheable, so you just try again.

a little test:

```
M = 10
res = [0 for i in range(M+1)]
for i in range(1000):
    res[generate()]+=1
plt.plot([r/1000 for r in res])
```

[image]